# Shipping items using "sales_order_shipment_save_after" or controller override is not working

Tags: magento2, shipping

I need to call some API on ship item from Magento but nothing is working.

Following things I already tried:

1. Use event/observer: `sales_order_shipment_save_after`. I thought this would work in Magento 2 because it did in Magento 1).
2. Override controller:  `\Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save` but controller overriding is also not working.

Comment: How is your issue?

Answer (score 7):

**--Sales Order Shipment Save After event:**

*app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_after">
        <observer name="sales_order_shipment_after"
                  instance="Company\Module\Observer\SalesOrderShipmentAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

*app/code/Company/Module/Observer/SalesOrderShipmentAfter.php*

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderShipmentAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();
        // Do some things

    }
}
```

**--Override controller**

We can use Plugin or preference.

*app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save"
                type="Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save" />
</config>
```

*app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php*

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment;

class Save extends \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save
{

}
```

Make sure that you clean Magento Cache and remove `var/generation`

Comment: hi I am getting unknown function getOrder() i am using event and obsertver

Comment: hello @Khoa, I am using this event and trying to get source_code from "inventory_shipment_source" table, but in this event data not present in the table for current shipment_id

Answer (score 0):

Handles synchronous insertion of the new entity into corresponding grid on certain events.

Used in the next events:

- sales_order_save_after
- sales_order_invoice_save_after
- sales_order_shipment_save_after
- sales_order_creditmemo_save_after

Works only if asynchronous grid indexing is disabled in global settings.