# Magento 2: How to get quantity to ship from when shipping the order?

Tags: magento2, shipping

I want to get the **quantity to ship** when i click on **submit shipment** botton. Following is the image and the array i got.

[image]

code:

```
$qtyShipped = $this->getRequest()->getParam('shipment');
var_dump($qtyShipped);
```

It gives output as

`array(2) { ["items"]=> array(1) { [31]=> string(1) "3" } ["comment_text"]=> string(0) "" }`

value 31 is changing for each order. Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Table Name `sales_order_item` -> Field Name: `qty_shipped` or `sales_shipment` -> `total_qty` for that `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment` & `getTotalQty`

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item')->load(<id>);
$getQtyShipped =  $_order->getQtyShipped();
```

Comment: Let me know if any issue @NitinPawar. Thanks

Comment: Yes u can user this value. Because it's already in DB. So get & Update if u Want then Save it again. @NitinPawar

Comment: No i think you not getting my question, i want to update the qty to ship value to 3 and it is 1 before. so when i access it from the database it will give me 1.

Comment: I think u need to set Shipment Quantity Value in Observer on Some Event llike when clicked on "Ship" button from Admin Right?

Comment: yes. I want to use this quantity when i ship the product.

Comment: Be clear when u want while click on "Ship" Button or by clicking on "Submit Shipment" Button @End of Page?

Comment: On clicking  "submit Shipment" button. I am working on shipment save.

Comment: U need to create Observer `sales_order_shipment_save_after`. For how to create Observer follow http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146034/magento-2-sales-order-shipment-save-after https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html

Comment: Please also look `magento\vendor\magento\module-sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice\Save.php`. U can also Override Controller http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-rewriting-classes-magento2/