# Magento 2.3 Hook an event in 'Submit Shipment' process in Sales Order View(Adminhtml) — New Shipment Form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, submit-shipment, new-shipment

I want to hook some event on **Submit Shipment** button in **Sales Order View New Shipment Form**.
I want the event to hook when admin clicks on **Submit Shipment** button.

Has anyone tried to do it before? Which file should be overridden?
Any reference please.

Please check the image below:

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend doing a plugin on \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save::execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this after making some researching

Through Overriding **New Shipment Save Controller** using a **Plugin**

> *app/code/Vendor/CustomModule/etc/adminhtml/di.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save"
                type="Vendor\CustomModule\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save" />
</config>
```

> *app/code/Company/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Order/Shipment/Save.php*

```
<?php

namespace Company\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment;

class Save extends \Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save
{
   //did my custom logic here 
}
```

reference: [Magento 2 - sales_order_shipment_save_after](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146034/magento-2-sales-order-shipment-save-after)