# Shipment Email not send automatically after creating a new shipment

Tags: email, magento2.3.2, email-scheduler

In Magento2.3 - My site **cannot be send shipment email automatically** after creating a new shipment. But it can send order email successfully when a new order is created. Does anyone know. How to fix the issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

normally when you create shipment if you checked **send mail to customer** than mail send, if not then email not send, and if you want to send mail automatically than try to add you code with in below url to send mail...

[Magento 2 - sales_order_shipment_save_after](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146034/magento-2-sales-order-shipment-save-after)