# When i disable an observer found this type of error "This observer does not exist to be disabled."

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, event-observer

[image]

Does any one have any idea about this type of issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your observer class is missing in events.xml file.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="my_module_event_after">
        <observer name="my_module_event_after_observer" instance="MyCompany\MyModule\Observer\MyEvent"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Change your observer name ,  applied and create class for observer.
and check it.

If you want to disable your event then make sure your module sequence. your custom module should be load after event implement module.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

**Updated Answer Applied and successfully disable the observer by change the required changes given below :**

check your config.php file set sequence in module.xml file like

```
<sequence> 
<module name="Magento_Sales" />
<module name="Magento_Payment" />
<module name="Magento_Directory" />
<module name="Magento_Config" />
</sequence>
```

remove generated and execute setup:upgrade command again

Comment: i am disabling magento custom observer which is already defined in Magento\InventoryShipping\Observer\SourceDeductionProcessor.........But in my case it was not disable the observer

Comment: Check sequence of your module.

Comment: your module should be loaded after inventory shipping.

Comment: keep your event.xml file in app/code/Company/Module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

That would help you for it.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146034/magento-2-sales-order-shipment-save-after

Comment: tried but same issue not disabling the observer that i want

Comment: check your config.php file 
set sequence in module.xml file like
<sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        <module name="Magento_Payment" />
        <module name="Magento_Directory" />
        <module name="Magento_Config" />
    </sequence>

remove generated and execute setup:upgrade  command again

Comment: Thank You Soo Much @S.P It really works

Comment: Welcome. so finally the issue was related sequence right?

Comment: Yes,it was related to the sequence

Answer (score 1):

You missed the ***instance*** node in that line, Also It is coming there becasue you have installed some quality tools, which phpstorm detects and make suggestions on it.

Also , If you are using any observer on your custom module try to name including the modulename with proper instance

Example :

```
<event name="catalog_product_save_after">
    <observer name="ced_tmall_product_save" instance="Ced\TMall\Observer\ProductSaveAfter" disabled="true"/>
</event>
```

Comment: with **instance** node also same error shows
And not disabling the observer

Comment: https://techflarestudio.com/how-to-disable-an-event-observer/
Please remove the generated and cache folder, rm - rf generated/ var/cache/.
After that again run di compile command and then cache flush and then check, whether it disabled or not

Comment: tried but not dsabled